# Delete service account role in GCP using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

How do we remove the owner role for service account in a project using terraform ? Ideally we need to remove only the role for this service account and keep the other assigned roles intact

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one of this two examples can help you, however, looks like there is no specific way to remove a role.

The first [example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_default_service_accounts):

```
resource "google_project_default_service_accounts" "my_project" {
  project = "my-project-id"
  action = "DELETE"
}
```

"action - (Required) The action to be performed in the default service accounts. Valid values are: DEPRIVILEGE, DELETE, DISABLE. Note that DEPRIVILEGE action will ignore the REVERT configuration in the restore_policy"

Or the [second one](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam_custom_role)

```
resource "google_project_iam_custom_role" "my-custom-role" {
  role_id     = "myCustomRole"
  title       = "My Custom Role"
  description = "A description"
  permissions = ["iam.roles.list", "iam.roles.create", "iam.roles.delete"]
}
```

"In addition to the arguments listed above, the following computed attributes are exported:

deleted - (Optional) The current deleted state of the role."

Comment: Thank you for the help will try this and feedback